# Element-wise multiplication of numpy arrays of complex numbers by broadcast

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, complex-numbers, array-broadcasting

I am trying to create a mandelbrot set by starting with a whole array of complex numbers and iterating on the appropriate values

```
# int array
int_array = np.array([i for i in range(10)])
squared_int = int_array ** 2
squares = np.array([i**2 for i in range(10)])
squared_int == squares
```

This gives the output I expect. An array containing the squares of the numbers 0-9

```
# complex array
complex_array = np.array([complex(i,i) for i in range(10)])
squared_complex = complex_array ** 2
complex_squares = np.array([complex(i,i)*complex(i,i) for i in range(10)])
squared_complex == complex_squares # array of True
```

I would expect the following statements to yield True, but they do not.

```
1+1j * 1+1j == complex_squares[1]
2+2j * 2+2j == squared_complex[2]
```

The content of complex_squares and squared_complex looks like this:

```
array([0.  +0.j, 0.  +2.j, 0.  +8.j, 0. +18.j, 0. +32.j, 0. +50.j,
   0. +72.j, 0. +98.j, 0.+128.j, 0.+162.j])
```

I also tried to check if complex(i,i) is equivalent with i+ij, which gave a weird result:

```
complex(1,1) == 1+1j # True
complex(1,1) ** 2 == 1+1j**2 # False
complex(1,1) ** 2 # 2j
1+1j ** 2         # 0j
1+1j * 1+1j       # 1+2j
complex(1,1) * complex(1,1) # 2j
```

Why is this happening?
Why is complex(i,i) and i+ij inconsistent?
I thought they were the same thing.

Comment: you need parenthesis. ie `(1+1j)**2` otherwise you are doing `1+1j*1j` which is not the square of a complex number

Comment: @Onyambu, that solves it for me. If you add your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by @Onyambu:

You need parentheses, i.e. `(1+1j)**2`. Otherwise you are doing `1+1j*1j`, which is not the square of a complex number.

Answer (score 0):

Like @André Sbrocco Figueiredo mentioned, the reason is in the fact you didn't use pharantases. Here is the fix:

```
print(complex(1,1) == 1+1j) # True
print(complex(1,1) ** 2 == (1+1j)**2) # True
print(complex(1,1) ** 2) # 2j
print((1+1j) ** 2) # 2j
print((1+1j) * (1+1j)) # 2j
print(complex(1,1) * complex(1,1)) # 2j
```

Cheers.